# CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL returning nil on any PDF file

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am not getting why * CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL* is returning nil. The file is not encrypted, no password and it is a simple pdf with text content. what could cause that.

```
var pdfDoc: CGPDFDocument!

pdfDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url)// the value is nil even though url and pdf file are valid
let pdfCatalog=CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog(pdfDoc)
```

Please note that the file does exist and the url is valid

Comment: url is a CFURLRef containing the path to the pdf file. I have also tried as CFURL and the result was still nil

Comment: What is the value at runtime?

Comment: at runtime it contains the path to the pdf (e.g: Users/../mytestpdf.pdf).

Comment: the problem was solved by adding "file:///" to the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was solved by adding "file:///" to the path. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/113941#113941

Comment: Sounds like you didn't actually make an NSURL from a filepath string.